# Can't Read appSettings until restart of application

Tags: c#

Can someone help me understand why after adding a value to the config file, I cannot read it into the application right away?  I do a refresh, but that doesn't work.  See below:

```
    public void AddConfig(string key_value, string actual_value)
    {
        // Open App.Config of executable
        System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Application.ExecutablePath);
        //If it exists, remove it first
        config.AppSettings.Settings.Remove(key_value);
        // Add an Application Setting.
        config.AppSettings.Settings.Add(key_value, actual_value);            
        // Save the configuration file.
        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
        // Force a reload of a changed section.            
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
        string blah = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key_value];
        MessageBox.Show(blah);
    }
```

The message box will show as null/blank.

If I restart the application and run another command to read the key value after startup, it will work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're experiencing is very likely a due to running the application from within the Visual Studio environment.

Run the .exe directly from the `Debug` or `Release` directory and the `RefreshSection()` method will work as expected.

If you want to see the changed value while debugging, you'll need to use  `AppSettings.Settings` instead of `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`:

```
string blah = config.AppSettings.Settings[key_value].Value
```

Comment: That was it....when I run from debug, it doesn't work.  When I run the actual app it works.